# Select from four mysql table with count and sum columns and where clause

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have 5 tables in my schema.

First is `opn`:

```
| opnID | submitID | emailID |       opnDate       | invalidOPN |
+-------+----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|   1   |    6     |    1    | 2014-10-15 11:45:50 |      2     |
|   2   |    6     |    2    | 2014-10-15 11:55:52 |      0     |
|   3   |    6     |    3    | 2014-10-15 12:41:52 |     10     |
|   4   |    7     |    2    | 2014-10-15 17:45:22 |      1     |
|   5   |    7     |    3    | 2014-10-16 00:45:55 |      5     |
|   6   |    6     |    5    | 2014-10-16 01:45:11 |      0     |
```

I also have `clk`:

```
| clkID| submitID | emailID |       clkDate        | invalidCLK |
+-------+----------+---------+---------------------+------------+
|   1   |    6     |    1    | 2014-10-15 11:45:55 |      1     |
|   2   |    6     |    2    | 2014-10-15 11:55:59 |      0     |
|   3   |    6     |    3    | 2014-10-15 12:42:52 |      5     |
|   4   |    7     |    3    | 2014-10-15 17:46:12 |      0     |
|   5   |    6     |    5    | 2014-10-16 00:46:55 |      0     |
```

A `users` table:

```
| userID | firstName | secondName |
+--------+-----------+------------+
|   1    |    john   |    smith   |
|   1    |   susan   |    bella   |
```

A `submission` table:

```
| submitID | userID |
+----------+--------+
|    6     |   1    |
|    7     |   2    |
```

I need to count opn.submitID to get the number of open and count clk.submitID to get the number of clicks and total of invalidclk and invalidopn for each users.

Here are my expected results:

```
| userID | fName | sName | numberOfOpen | SUM(opn.invalidOPN) | numberOfClicks | SUM(clk.invalidCLK) |
+--------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
|   1    | john  | smith |      4       |          12         |        4       |         6           |
|   2    | susan | bella |      2       |           6         |        1       |         0           |
```

I tried with those two queries but I don't reach the result that I need

```
SELECT users.userID, users.FirstName, users.SecondName, count(opn.submitID) as "Number of Opens", sum(opn.InvalidOPN) as "Number of invalid Opens"

FROM users 

RIGHT JOIN ( submission INNER JOIN opn ON opn.submitID = submission.submitID and OPNDate between "2013-10-01 00:00:00" AND "2014-10-31 23:59:59" ) ON submission.UserID = users.UserID   group by users.userID 

UNION

SELECT users.userID, users.FirstName, users.SecondName, count(clk.submitID) as "Number of clicks", sum(clk.InvalidCLK) as "Number of invalid clicks"
FROM users
RIGHT JOIN ( submission INNER JOIN clk ON clk.submitID = submission.submitID and CLKDate between "2013-10-01 00:00:00" AND "2014-10-31 23:59:59") ON submission.UserID = users.UserID  group by users.userID
```

---

```
SELECT users.userID, users.FirstName, users.SecondName, count(opn.submitID) as "Number of Opens", sum(opn.InvalidOPN) as "Number of invalid Opens", count(clk.submitID) as "Number of clicks", sum(clk.InvalidCLK) as "Number of invalid clicks"

FROM users, submission, clk, opn 

where opn.submitID = submission.submitID and clk.submitID = submission.submitID 
And CLKDate between "2013-10-01 00:00:00" AND "2014-10-31 23:59:59" 
AND submission.UserID = users.UserID  group by users.userID
```

---

Please help me, and show me what I need to change.

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with doing this is that you land up joining the tables against each other and getting every combination of opn and clk records. In such a situation you land up needing to use *COUNT(DISTINCT some_field_name)* to count the unique values:-

```
SELECT users.UserId
        COUNT(DISTINCT opn.OPNID),
        COUNT(DISTINCT clk.CLKID)
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN submission ON users.UserId = submission.UserId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN opn ON submission.SubmitID = opn.SubmitID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clk ON submission.SubmitID = clk.SubmitID 
GROUP BY users.UserId
```

However that doesn't help in this case as you also need the sum of the invalid___ fields.

As such I would suggest using a couple of sub queries, one for clk and one for opn. These get the counts and the sums grouped by the user id. And the results of these sub queries are joined to the users table.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT users.UserId,
        users.fName,
        users.sName,
        numberOfOpen,
        COALESCE(invalidopnsum, 0),
        numberOfClicks,
        COALESCE(invalidclksum, 0)
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT submission.UserId, COUNT(opn.SubmitID) AS numberOfOpen, SUM(opn.InvalidOPN) AS invalidopnsum
    FROM submission 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN opn ON submission.SubmitID = opn.SubmitID 
    GROUP BY submission.UserId
) opn1
ON users.UserId = opn1.UserId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT submission.UserId, COUNT(clk.SubmitID) AS numberOfClicks, SUM(clk.InvalidCLK) AS invalidclksum
    FROM submission 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clk ON submission.SubmitID = clk.SubmitID 
    GROUP BY submission.UserId
) clk1
ON users.UserId = clk1.UserId
```

Comment: You're just missing a comma after `COALESCE(invalidopnsum, 0)`. Otherwise, this returns the right [results.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b164/7)

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you think. All you need to do is join all of your tables together and user some aggregate functions. You can join users with submissions on the userID column, and you can join that with the clk and opn tables using the submitID column. You can use COUNT() to get the number of opens and clicks, and SUM() to get the totals of the invalid column. However, doing these calculations all at once won't work, as some facts will be duplicated, so I recommend you do each query separately, and join them.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.userID, t.firstName, t.secondName, t.numOpen, t.totalInvalidOpen, w.numClick, w.totalInvalidClick
FROM (SELECT u.userID, u.firstName, u.secondName, COUNT(*) AS numOpen, SUM(o.invalidOPN) AS totalInvalidOpen
      FROM users u
      JOIN submission s ON s.userID = u.userID
      JOIN opn o ON o.submitID = s.submitID
      GROUP BY u.userID
      ) t
JOIN (SELECT u.userID, u.firstName, u.secondName, COUNT(*) AS numClick, SUM(c.invalidCLK) AS totalInvalidClick
      FROM users u
      JOIN submission s ON s.userID = u.userID
      JOIN clk c ON c.submitID = s.submitID
      GROUP BY u.userID
      ) w
ON w.userID = t.userID;
```

And it works! Here is your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b164/4). *NOTE:* Your result set in the question is incorrect, as the total invalid open for user 1 is only 12.

Comment: Minor issue is that this will only bring back a user if they have records on both the opn and the clk table.

Comment: Good catch. So should I left join the users table as you did?

Comment: @Kickstart I think I should just concede to your answer haha. If I change mine to a left join I'd have the exact same as yours.

Comment: Possible, but it might be the OP only wants records that are in both opn and clk (not 100% clear from the examples). With mine I would just change the outer joins to inner joins to give that.